Amazon webscraper : products not adding to Mongoose collection
The issue I'm facing is that despite observing traffic on my MongoDB database, the products I expect to be stored within it are not present. I scrape product data from Amazon and attempt to store it in the database using a defined schema and model. Despite successful scraping and apparent database activity, the products don't appear in the database collection.
Note that in the terminal, despite successful scraping, I still receive an error message that I'm unable to resolve. This error may be a contributing factor to the issue at hand.
What I get in the console :

Compiled / in 3s (864 modules)
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the top-level render call using <div>. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
 GET / 200 in 3305ms
 Compiled in 250ms (303 modules)
MONGODB Connected
{
  url: 'https://www.amazon.fr/Acer-Nitro-KG241YS3biipf-BluelightShield-Inclinable/dp/B0C28QPGR2/ref=pd_ci_mcx_mh_mcx_views_0?pd_rd_w=6Um3V&content-id=amzn1.sym.599bf194-df9f-4215-9a04-668b64035e9b%3Aamzn1.symc.45dc5f4c-d617-4dba-aa26-2cadef3da899&pf_rd_p=599bf194-df9f-4215-9a04-668b64035e9b&pf_rd_r=GZT3RR107R9VMD4YD53C&pd_rd_wg=xXitn&pd_rd_r=faaf1dc0-3548-448f-a812-ecb8c374ca29&pd_rd_i=B0C28QPGR2',
  currency: '€',
  image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71GazIpwJ+L._AC_SX355_.jpg',
  title: 'Acer Nitro KG241YS3biipf - Écran PC Gaming 24" Full HD, 180Hz (1920x1080, 16:9, FreeSync, 1ms VRB, 250 Nits, Comfyview, BluelightShield, 2xHDMI 2.0/1xDP 1.2) Moniteur PC Inclinable, Couleur Noir',
  currentPrice: 139139,
  originalPrice: 1449014490429609,
  priceHistory: [],
  discountRate: NaN,
  outOfStock: false,
  description: ''Ecran pc amazon",
  lowestPrice: 139139,
  highestPrice: 139139,
  averagePrice: 139139,
  reviewsCount: 3
}
Failed to scrape product
 POST / 200 in 3188ms

Here is some of my code :
"use server"

import Product from "../models/product.model";
import { connectTodb } from "../mongoose";
import { scrapeAmazonProduct } from "../scraper";
import { getAveragePrice, getHighestPrice, getLowestPrice } from "../util";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function scrapeAndStoreProduct(productURL: string) {
  if (!productURL) return;

  try {
    connectTodb();
    const scrapedProduct: any = await scrapeAmazonProduct(productURL);
    
    if (!scrapedProduct) {
      console.log("Failed to scrape product");
      return; // Stop execution if product scraping failed
    }
    let product = scrapedProduct;

    // Check if scrapedProduct is an object and has a url property
    if (typeof scrapedProduct === 'object' && scrapedProduct !== null && 'url' in scrapedProduct) {
      const existingProduct = await Product.findOne({ url: scrapedProduct.url });
      if (existingProduct) {
        const updatedPriceHistory : any = [
          ...existingProduct.priceHistory,
          { price: scrapedProduct.currentPrice }
        ]
        product = {
          ...scrapedProduct,
          priceHistory: updatedPriceHistory,
          lowestPrice: getLowestPrice(updatedPriceHistory),
          highestPrice: getHighestPrice(updatedPriceHistory),
          averagePrice: getAveragePrice(updatedPriceHistory)

        }
      }
    }
    const newProduct = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
      {url: scrapedProduct.url},
      product,
      {upsert: true, new:true}
      );
    revalidatePath(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to create/update product: ${error.message}`)
  }
}


export async function getProductById(productId: string){
  try {
    connectTodb();
  } catch (error) {
    
  }
}

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { connectTodb } from "../mongoose";


const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: {type : String, required:true, unique:true},
  currency: {type: String, required:true},
  image: {type: String, required:true},
  title: {type: String, required:true},
  currentPrice: {type: Number, required:true},
  originalPrice: {type: Number, required:true},
  priceHistory: [
    {
      prices: {type: Number, required: true},
      date: {type:Date, default: Date.now}
    },
  ],
  lowestPrice: {type: Number},
  highestPrice: {type: Number},
  averagePrice: {type: Number},
  discountRate: {type: Number},
  description: {type: String},
  isOutOfStock: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  users: [{email: {type: String, required: true}}],
}, {timestamps: true});

const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

export default Product;


import mongoose from "mongoose";


let isConnected = false;

export const connectTodb = async () => {
  mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
  // Vérifie si MONGODB_URI est défini
  if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
    console.error('MONGODB_URI is not defined');
    return;
  }

  if(isConnected) return console.log('=> using existing database connection');
  
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
    isConnected = true;
    console.log('MONGODB Connected');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', error);
  }
};


